# How to access indices of an NSDictionary, and convert that key’s value to an Int in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, integer, nsdictionary

I’m trying to access indices of an NSDictionary, and convert that key’s value to an Int using Swift.

I’m also using an API to fetch data. The API response is what I’m using to create an initial dictionary out of, then I create a dictionary out of the “hours” part of the API response. The API call part of my code is working, so I’ve only included code related to accessing the hoursDictionary.

I’ve tried using [[[String: Any]]] instead of [NSDictionary] for hoursDictionary after looking up this problem online, but this did not work for me.

The error I keep getting is at the if statement line: if Int(hoursDictionary[0][5][2]) > Integer for a certain time { , and the error text is: “Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts”. I know this is because the NSDictionary’s key’s value that I’m trying to access has a value of type Any.

I think the error is somewhere in this if statement, and is related to changing the data type of that part in the dictionary that I’m trying to access to an Int.

The API that I’m using is the Yelp Fusion API, and the API search that I’m using is “Business Details”. Here’s a link to this documentation: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business .

An example of the API response body that is being returned and what I’m accessing is the following:

```
{
  "id": "WavvLdfdP6g8aZTtbBQHTw",
  "alias": "gary-danko-san-francisco",
  "name": "Gary Danko",
  "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/CPc91bGzKBe95aM5edjhhQ/o.jpg",
  "is_claimed": true,
  "is_closed": false,
  "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/gary-danko-san-francisco?adjust_creative=wpr6gw4FnptTrk1CeT8POg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_lookup&utm_source=wpr6gw4FnptTrk1CeT8POg",
  "phone": "+14157492060",
  "display_phone": "(415) 749-2060",
  "review_count": 5296,
  "categories": [
    {
      "alias": "newamerican",
      "title": "American (New)"
    },
    {
      "alias": "french",
      "title": "French"
    },
    {
      "alias": "wine_bars",
      "title": "Wine Bars"
    }
  ],
  "rating": 4.5,
  "location": {
    "address1": "800 N Point St",
    "address2": "",
    "address3": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "zip_code": "94109",
    "country": "US",
    "state": "CA",
    "display_address": [
      "800 N Point St",
      "San Francisco, CA 94109"
    ],
    "cross_streets": ""
  },
  "coordinates": {
    "latitude": 37.80587,
    "longitude": -122.42058
  },
  "photos": [
    "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/CPc91bGzKBe95aM5edjhhQ/o.jpg",
    "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/FmXn6cYO1Mm03UNO5cbOqw/o.jpg",
    "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/HZVDyYaghwPl2kVbvHuHjA/o.jpg"
  ],
  "price": "$$$$",
  "hours": [
    {
      "open": [
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 0
        },
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 1
        },
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 2
        },
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 3
        },
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 4
        },
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 5
        },
        {
          "is_overnight": false,
          "start": "1730",
          "end": "2200",
          "day": 6
        }
      ],
      "hours_type": "REGULAR",
      "is_open_now": false
    }
  ],
  "transactions": [],
  "special_hours": [
    {
      "date": "2019-02-07",
      "is_closed": null,
      "start": "1600",
      "end": "2000",
      "is_overnight": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Snippet of my code:

`FetchData.swift`

```
                        /// Read data as JSON
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                        
                        /// Main dictionary
                        guard let responseDictionary = json as? NSDictionary else {return}
                        
                        /// Creating hours dictionary,
                        guard let hoursDictionary = responseDictionary.value(forKey: "hours") as? [NSDictionary] else {return}
                        
                        if let endTimeAsString = hoursDictionary["open"][5]["end"] as? String,
                        let endTimeAsInt = Int(endTimeAsString),
                        endTimeAsInt > An integer representing a certain time {

                          // Do something
                            
}
```

Comment: You should try not to use the `NS...` classes in Swift; use the native Swift equivalents.  Even better, create some structs that implement `Codable` and use `JSONDecoder`.  You can use https://app.quicktype.io to create the struct code for you from the JSON

Comment: Thank you for this information. I’ll be sure to look at this solution more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a dictionary's [nth] index like you would an array because a dictionary is an *unordered* collection. Instead you would have to do something like this **[CORRECTED]** `hoursDictionary[0]["open"][5]["end"]`, or whatever sequence to get the value you need.

Or, I tend to split this up so I can ensure I am processing each step correctly like so:

```
guard let hoursDictionaries = responseDictionary.value(forKey: "hours") as? [NSDictionary] else {return}
                        
if let firstHoursDictionary = hoursDictionaries[0] as? NSDictionary,
   let openDictionarys = firstHoursDictionary["open"] as? [NSDictionary],
   let firstOpenDictionary = openDictionarys[5] as? NSDictionary,
   let endTimeAsString = firstOpenDictionary["end"] as? String,
   let endTimeAsInt = Int(endTimeAsString),
   endTimeAsInt > someInt {

    // Do something
}

// Remember, you can always check what type the compiler is inferring something 
// to be by right-clicking on the variable name and clicking `Show Quick Help`.
```

Comment: I tried this, and used ```if hoursDictionary["open"][5]["end"] as! Int > Integer of a certain time {``` but got the error message: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'". How would I solve this? I've looked this up online, and couldn't find a quick fix.

Comment: Looking at the JSON dictionary, you can see that the value that is returned by `hoursDictionary["open"][5]["end"]` is of type `String` (I.e. "2200"). You know it's a `String` because it is surrounded by double quotes. To simplify this, I would break the if statement up into multiple parts for clarity. See my edited answer to see what I would do. This way, you can first get the value as a `String`, then as an `Int`, then check the condition of whether it's greater than a certain time, all in one if/else block.

Comment: Also, please accept my answer if it answers your question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the response and updated answer. This makes sense. When I tried your example with the if/let block, I got the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'" at the first line in the code example (reads ```if let endTimeAsString = hoursDictionary["open"][5]["end"] as? String,``` ). How do I solve this? I've looked this up online, and couldn't quickly find a working solution.

Comment: Can you please post your updated code. I think there may be a syntax error prior to this if/else block. It shouldn't be expected a `Range<Int>` type in an if/else block.

Comment: Sure thing, just updated and added more code to the initial post.

Comment: Okay my apologies, I read the dictionary structure slightly wrong. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: No worries, thank you very much for the help. I had tried a solution similar to this earlier (didn’t post it here), but I couldn’t get it to work. I’ll try this when I get back to my computer in a few hours and update. Also, thank you for the reminder at the end of your updated answer.

Comment: No problem, lemme know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Just tried it out, and it worked! Thank you!